# How do I change the version of GCC that I'm using? Why does GCC still seem to work despite bash telling me the gcc command was not found?

Tags: linux, gcc

I was trying to follow [this](http://www.valvers.com/open-software/raspberry-pi/step01-bare-metal-programming-in-cpt1/) tutorial for an introduction to bare metal programming in C on a raspberry pi. One of the first things it recommends is to install the gcc 4.7 toolchain instead of what I currently had installed, the 4.8 version. I have, despite all of my googling, been unable to make this work.

I have tried using the `update-alternatives` command, with gcc-4.7 selected, to no avail. The command `gcc` is met with a `bash: gcc: command not found` error. So I obviously can't use `gcc -v` or `gcc --version`.

Whenever I run the build scripts that generate a usable kernel image file, the command says it has used `arm-none-eabi`'s 4.8 version. I'm totally unsure of how to use the 4.7 version in its stead.

Here are the contents of that particular script, followed by its output when I run it.

```
#!/bin/sh

arm-none-eabi-gcc -O0 -DRPIBPLUS -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv6zk -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -nostartfiles -g armc-03.c -o kernel.elf
arm-none-eabi-objcopy kernel.elf -O binary kernel.img
```

And the output:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000008000
```

The `/4.8/` is what I hope you'll takeaway from the command, though I assume it's throwing that warning because I'm using an "unexpected" compiler. (Fun fact, when I test it in my Pi it doesn't work)

Under these conditions, how can I make gcc use the 4.7 version when compiling C code for use with bare metal programming on a raspberry pi?

I'd like to add that the standard `./configure`, `make`, and `make install` commands are also not working. When I `cd` into the directory of the extracted tarball, running `./configure` gives me a no such file or directory error.

Comment: What distribution and arch are you using for build and how did you install current 4.8 toolchain?  The tutorial assumes installing 4.7 cross toolchain using a tarball available from [here](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/4.7/4.7-2013-q3-update).  Why not just extract it and set `PATH` accordingly?

Comment: Crunchbang (rip) and 64bit. I just used `sudo apt-get install build-essentials`  when I first did it. Rerunning that command or variations doesn't seem to affect anything. I did download that tarball, and I did try a couple variations of changing my PATH, although again I didn't notice much difference. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: I apologize for the double post, but I'm no longer able to edit my comment. I'd like to add that the standard `./configure`, `make`, and `make install` commands are also not working. When I `cd` into the directory of the extracted tarball, running `./configure` gives me a `no such file or directory` error.

Comment: Please [update your original question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/229708/edit) with this new information. Don't leave it in the comments as it can get lost.